# Magento Multi currency issue if base currency is other than USD

Tags: magento, paypal

I have installed multi currency module in magento  ver(1.7.0.2) single store. Allowed  currencies are INR and USD. INR is the base currency.

When display currency is in INR and checkout through paypal it redirects to PayPal with correct USD value. For example, if Product Value is INR 3000 and shipping INR 2000 then the amount carried to PayPal site $50 and Shipping $34 total as $84

If the display currency is USD and checkout through PayPal it redirects to PayPal  with wrong amount. That is Product Value is $3000 and Shipping $ 2000 Total showing $7000.

I need help in rectifying this issue. Correct amount should be redirected to PayPal for both the currency display.